# Python: How do I make a for loop append data to a list when the format is non-standard?

Tags: python

I'm looking to read some marker data into data structures using Python. So far, I have successfully read every Marker name into a single list (there are 2,000 of those).

The data I have was originally in Excel, but I converted it into a .txt file.

The header data in the file was removed and assigned to variables using readline().

Every line with a marker name begins with a double quotation mark (") so I was able to easily gain that information and store it as a list.

Each line with the data for that marker is indented 2 spaces and there are lines that begin with either "a" , "b" , or "h". I want to get these into a data structure. I've tried both lists and strings, but both are returned as empty. The data under each marker name is a block with the three letters "a", "b", and "h" with each letter representing an individual in a population (there are 250). The tricky thing is that there are 5 letters separated by a single space, but then those 5-letter blocks are separated from other 5-letter blocks by two spaces.

Example:

```
"BK_12 (a,h,b) ; 1"
  b a a a b  a b a a a  b a b a a  a a a a a  a a a b b  a a b a h  b   
  a a a a a  a a a a a  a a a a a  a b a a a  a h a a a  a a a a a  h
  a a b a a  a h a a a  a h a h a  a a a a a  a a b a a  a a a a h  a
  a a a b a  a a a a a  a a b a a  b b a b a  h a b a a  a b a a a  h 
  a a a a
```

That part I don't really need help with, but just included for reference of how the file looks. My ultimate goal is to use phenotype data to find markers associated with a specific phenotype.

I used a for loop to accomplish this so far. My code is below. EDIT: I tried indexing from position 2, rather an searching from position 0 for an empty space. I thought this would work. The else: statement was meant to tell me whether or not it was recognizing the elif statements. Nothing was returned, so I'm assuming it is working in that regard, but it isn't appending.

```
Markers = []
Genotype_Data = []

for line in infile:
    line=line.rstrip()
    if (line[0] == '"'):
        line=line.rstrip()
        Markers.append(line)
    elif (line[2] == 'a'):
        line=line.rstrip()
        Genotype_Data.append(line)
    elif (line[2] == 'b'):
        line=line.rstrip()
        Genotype_Data.append(line)
    elif (line[2] == 'h'):
        line=line.rstrip()
        Genotype_Data.append(line)
    else:
        print("Something isn't right!")
```

Comment: Could you give a little input example?

Comment: I'm trying to enter an example, but it keeps changing the format. Thank you roippi for fixing my code format in the initial post.

Comment: Edit your post, don't post the example here in comments.

Comment: I can't add it because it is being interpreted as code and says it is not formatted properly.

Comment: No, no. Edit your post here in stackoverflow, and add your input.

Comment: Stack overflow is rejecting it as improperly formatted.

Comment: To add example input to your question, just copy and paste several lines from the input file after the code you have already. Afterwards, select those lines and format them as though they were code (which will indent each added line by four spaces).

Comment: Your example data doesn't seem to match your description...

Comment: Part of the right is cut off, but this is what the input looks like.

Comment: Don't use correlated arrays (lists). Use objects which hold all of the information, and then have one list of those objects.

Comment: OK, how many groups of 5 letters are there on each line? Also why does the last line only have one group of 4 letters in it?

Comment: @Marcin: That's the least of the OP's problems, IMO.

Comment: @martineau, there are 10 groups of 5 letters (each one is 5x5) so that is 250. There are only 4 letters on the last line because the exact number of individuals in the population is 254, so it isn't even.

Comment: @Marcin: Do you think I should use something like a dictionary? I don't care what the order is exactly. I could use the name of each individual as the key and the genotype as the value.

Comment: @MatthewHaas Maybe? It depends on how you want to access the objects. I just recommend that you don't use multiple correlated datastructure.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what your goal is.

Maybe this helps you achieve it:

```
print(line.split()) # just a and b, ...
['b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'h', 'b']
>>> print(line.split(' ')) # a b, ... and '' where a new block starts
['', '', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', '', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', '', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', '', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', '', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'h', '', 'b', '', '', '']
>>> '  x x  '.strip()
'x x'
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up doing something similar, but I need to store the information so I can use it later, so I did a for loop where a,b, or h appends to a list and the spaces fall under the 'else' option.


The goal is to get these data into a usable form. I need to compare all 2,000+ (genetic) markers for all 254 individuals. There will be an additional input file with disease data (resistant and susceptible). The final goal is to find a handful of markers that are significantly associated with resistance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear about what format you want the data to end up in the`Genotype_Data`list, but you should be able to tweak that portion of the following as required:

```
Markers = []
Genotype_Data = []
INDIVIDUALS = set('abh')

with open('genotype_data.txt', mode='rt') as infile:
    line = infile.next().rstrip()  # read first line of file
    if line[0] == '"':
        Markers.append(line)
    else:
        raise ValueError('marker line expected')

    geno_accumulator = []
    for line in infile:  # read remainder of file
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line[0] == '"':
            Genotype_Data.append(geno_accumulator)
            geno_accumulator = []
            Markers.append(line)
        elif line[2] in INDIVIDUALS:
            geno_accumulator.append(line)
        else:
            raise ValueError('unrecognized line of input data encountered')

    if geno_accumulator:  # append the final bit of genotype data
        Genotype_Data.append(geno_accumulator)

print 'Markers:', Markers
print 'Genotype_Data:', Genotype_Data
```